# Is there any simple way to see which mongodb indexes are being used?

Tags: mongodb

We've accumulated a large number of indexes on one of our mongodb collections, and it would be good to remove some of these if possible.  However, it's quite difficult to know which indexes are in active use by the applicaiton, and which (if any) are now obsolete.

Does anyone know of any tools/techniques to analyse which indexes are being used?

Edit: Mongo v3.0.5

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @Stennie - v3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MongoDB 3.0 does not have a direct method of identifying unused indexes.

MongoDB 3.2 does improve upon this with the introduction of $indexStats, which shows index accesses:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/

A few suggestions:

- Try to identify any indexes that may be prefixes of one another, as these can be redundant. Keep in mind that ordering of indexes can matter
- As Jacob mentioned, using explain plan can help to identify if a query is using an index. PlanCache.getPlansByQuery() will expands upon this by showing which query plans are currently cached by the database for specific query patterns:
  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/PlanCache.getPlansByQuery/#PlanCache.getPlansByQuery

Answer (score 1):

Post MongoDB 3.2 you have the $indexStats that lets you know which indexes are being used and to what extent. I put together a blog post on this - https://scalegrid.io/blog/how-to-find-unused-indexes-in-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

You can use query.explain() on individual queries to return the query plan for that query. You can look into that further here. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

Other things you might want to look into :

In the output of serverStatus:

```
scanned
scanAndOrder
```

In the output of collStats:

```
totalIndexSize
indexSizes
```

In the output of dbStats:

```
dbStats.indexes
dbStats.indexSize
```